# Filter Through Nested Dicts

Tags: python, json

I have a Python script that goes as this (below), and I am having trouble figuring out how I can filter through dictionaries inside of a dictionary. I want it to be done where if there is the object property `'type': 'data'`, then the object itself will be removed. If it helps, I am trying to filter out `languages.yml` from [GitHub/linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml).

```py
import json

file = open('languages.json', 'r')
data = json.load(file)
print(data)

for language in data:
    if data[language]['type'] == 'data':
        del language
file.close()

print(data)
file2 = open('langs.json', 'w')
file2.write(json.dumps(data))
file2.close()
print("Finished.")
```

Comment: inside your if, have you tried ```del data[language]``` Note ```data[language]``` instead of just ```language```

Comment: I think it works but I got `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

The first is that `del language` is the key value but not a reference to it in the dictionary. So you need to change that to `del data[language]` to actually delete the key and values in the dictionary.

The second is that you are looping based on the size of the dictionary. Change `for language in data` to loop through the keys by doing `for language in data.keys()` and that will handle the issue with the dictionary resizing.

The final code:

```
for language in data.keys():
    if data[language]['type'] == 'data':
        del data[language]
```

Also as another optimization. You can close file after you assign the contents to data because you no longer use it. This will honestly only make a difference when the contents of file is rather large because it will free up memory to be used.